# UIActionSheet to open up Mail Application iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, uiactionsheet, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

This issue is something which has me stumped, so hopefully someone can help.  I have an UIActionSheet on a view which has three options in.  One which takes my user to a new view, one to share via email and one to share via SMS.

I have the UIActionSheet created which works without issue, the new view part of the AlertSheet also works.  I have imported the Message.UI framework and set up the mail and SMS pickers and composers which are fine.  However, I am having trouble setting the two 'buttons' on the UIActionSheet to open up the mail and SMS.

Normally i would do this through interface builder and connect a UIButton to the actions I have created, but because this is a UIActionSheet it can't be done that way.  Sorry for the LONG code but I felt I needed to show everything, so please see below;

```
-(IBAction)showActionSheet {
    UIActionSheet *actionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@"Choose an Option" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" destructiveButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"Application Support",@"Share Via Email",@"Share Via SMS",nil];
    [actionSheet showInView:self.view];
    [actionSheet release];
}
-(void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
    if(buttonIndex == 0) {
    AppSupportView *controller = [[AppSupportView alloc] initWithNibName:@"AppSupportView" bundle:nil];
    controller.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
    [self presentModalViewController:controller animated:YES];
    [controller release];
    }

    if(buttonIndex == 1) {

    }

    if(buttonIndex == 2) {

    }

}

- (void)dealloc {
    [feedbackMsg release];
    [super dealloc];
}

- (void)viewDidUnload {
    self.feedbackMsg = nil;
}

-(IBAction)showMailPicker:(id)sender {
    // The MFMailComposeViewController class is only available in iPhone OS 3.0 or later. 
    // So, we must verify the existence of the above class and provide a workaround for devices running 
    // earlier versions of the iPhone OS. 
    // We display an email composition interface if MFMailComposeViewController exists and the device 
    // can send emails. Display feedback message, otherwise.
    Class mailClass = (NSClassFromString(@"MFMailComposeViewController"));

    if (mailClass != nil) {
        //[self displayMailComposerSheet];
        // We must always check whether the current device is configured for sending emails
        if ([mailClass canSendMail]) {
            [self displayMailComposerSheet];
        }
        else {
            feedbackMsg.hidden = NO;
            feedbackMsg.text = @"Device not configured to send mail.";
        }
    }
    else    {
        feedbackMsg.hidden = NO;
        feedbackMsg.text = @"Device not configured to send mail.";
    }
}

-(IBAction)showSMSPicker:(id)sender {
    //  The MFMessageComposeViewController class is only available in iPhone OS 4.0 or later. 
    //  So, we must verify the existence of the above class and log an error message for devices
    //      running earlier versions of the iPhone OS. Set feedbackMsg if device doesn't support 
    //      MFMessageComposeViewController API.
    Class messageClass = (NSClassFromString(@"MFMessageComposeViewController"));

    if (messageClass != nil) {          
        // Check whether the current device is configured for sending SMS messages
        if ([messageClass canSendText]) {
            [self displaySMSComposerSheet];
        }
        else {  
            feedbackMsg.hidden = NO;
            feedbackMsg.text = @"Device not configured to send SMS.";

        }
    }
    else {
        feedbackMsg.hidden = NO;
        feedbackMsg.text = @"Device not configured to send SMS.";
    }
}

// Displays an email composition interface inside the application. Populates all the Mail fields. 
-(void)displayMailComposerSheet 
{
    MFMailComposeViewController *picker = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
    picker.mailComposeDelegate = self;

    [picker setSubject:@"My BMR Index Rating from Total:Health App"];


    // Set up recipients
    //NSArray *toRecipients = [NSArray arrayWithObject:@""]; 

     //[picker setToRecipients:toRecipients];
    NSString *emailSharing = @"I Just discovered that I have a Target Heart Rate of";
    // Fill out the email body text
    [picker setMessageBody:emailSharing isHTML:YES];

    [self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];
    [picker release];
}

// Displays an SMS composition interface inside the application. 
-(void)displaySMSComposerSheet 
{
    MFMessageComposeViewController *picker = [[MFMessageComposeViewController alloc] init];
    picker.messageComposeDelegate = self;
    NSString *SMSShare = @"I Just discovered that I have a Target Heart Rate of";
    // Fill out the email body text
    picker.body = SMSShare;

    [self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];
    [picker release];
}

// Dismisses the email composition interface when users tap Cancel or Send. Proceeds to update the 
// message field with the result of the operation.
- (void)mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController*)controller 
          didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result error:(NSError*)error {

    feedbackMsg.hidden = NO;
    // Notifies users about errors associated with the interface
    switch (result)
    {
        case MFMailComposeResultCancelled:
            feedbackMsg.text = @"Result: Mail sending canceled";
            break;
        case MFMailComposeResultSaved:
            feedbackMsg.text = @"Result: Mail saved";
            break;
        case MFMailComposeResultSent:
            feedbackMsg.text = @"Result: Mail sent";
            break;
        case MFMailComposeResultFailed:
            feedbackMsg.text = @"Result: Mail sending failed";
            break;
        default:
            feedbackMsg.text = @"Result: Mail not sent";
            break;
    }
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}


// Dismisses the message composition interface when users tap Cancel or Send. Proceeds to update the 
// feedback message field with the result of the operation.
- (void)messageComposeViewController:(MFMessageComposeViewController *)controller 
                 didFinishWithResult:(MessageComposeResult)result {

    feedbackMsg.hidden = NO;
    // Notifies users about errors associated with the interface
    switch (result)
    {
        case MessageComposeResultCancelled:
            feedbackMsg.text = @"Result: SMS sending canceled";
            break;
        case MessageComposeResultSent:
            feedbackMsg.text = @"Result: SMS sent";
            break;
        case MessageComposeResultFailed:
            feedbackMsg.text = @"Result: SMS sending failed";
            break;
        default:
            feedbackMsg.text = @"Result: SMS not sent";
            break;
    }
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}

@end
```

The issue is obviously that I dont know how to proceed with the (if buttonIndex ==1) etc piece of code to open the mail and SMS

```
-(void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
    if(buttonIndex == 0) {
    AppSupportView *controller = [[AppSupportView alloc] initWithNibName:@"AppSupportView" bundle:nil];
    controller.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
    [self presentModalViewController:controller animated:YES];
    [controller release];
    }

    if(buttonIndex == 1) {

    }

    if(buttonIndex == 2) {

    }

}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

looks like all your needed methods are there already..
just add `[self showMailPicker:nil]` or `[self showSMSPicker:nil]` to

```
if(buttonIndex == 1) {

}

if(buttonIndex == 2) {

}
```

if your second button from the top is your sms button, add showSMSPicker to buttonIndex == 1

Comment: Thank you so much, I knew it would be something simple. I had previously put [self showMailPicker]; but had not included the :nil and was getting a method does not exist, reverts to id error with an App Crash.  That worked perfectly.  Thank you

Comment: if you don't use these methods from within Interface Builder you could also just change your method declaration from "-(IBAction)showMailPicker:(id)sender;" to "-(void)showMailPicker;".. then you can call these methods with [self showMailPicker];

Comment: Ah, that was my error. I did change them from IBAction to void, however I left the :(id)sender; on it.  Thanks again.